# Indy 10.5.8.0 + XE2 + Windows 10 "Access violation at address 00000000. Read of address 00000000"

Tags: delphi, openssl, indy10

The code below works perfectly on Windows 7 machines 32 and 64 bits, it posts data to a https server on 5443 port and receive its response. However, machines with windows 10 it throws an `Access violation at address 00000000. Read of address 00000000` message.

Some situations we might consider:

```
 - Delphi XE2
 - Indy 10.5.8.0  
 - [OpenSSL v1.1.1g][1] 
 - Windows 10 Version 1909
 - No firewall and antivirus for tests
```

Here's the code:

```
_idHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(Self);
_idHTTP.AllowCookies := True;
_idHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
_idHTTP.HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams];
_idHTTP.ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication := False;
_idHTTP.Request.Accept := 'text/html, */*';
_idHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
_idHTTP.Request.ContentLength := -1;
_idHTTP.Request.ContentRangeEnd := -1;
_idHTTP.Request.ContentRangeInstanceLength := -1;
_idHTTP.Request.ContentRangeStart := -1;
_idHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)';
_idHTTP.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(_idHTTP);

_idHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
_idHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Content-Type', 'application/json');
_idHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Accept', 'application/json');


try
    json := '{user: "<myuser>", pass: "<mypass>"}';
    RequestBody := TStringStream.Create(json, TEncoding.UTF8);
    try
        sRet := _idHTTP.Post('https://10.200.200.213:5443/auth', RequestBody);
    except
        raise ex;
    end;
finally
    _idHTTP.Free;
end;
```

Edit: 
The error message is throwing by the line

```
sRet := _idHTTP.Post('https://10.200.200.213:5443/auth', RequestBody);
```

Comment: Indy doesn't support openssl 1.1.1.

Comment: And … the line that throws is … ?

Comment: @TomBrunberg sRet := _idHTTP.Post('https://10.200.200.213:5443/auth', RequestBody);

Comment: @zed So, witch version should I install?

Comment: @zed - "*Indy doesn't support openssl 1.1.1*" - [yet](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/183), but there is [work in progress](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/299) for that.

Comment: @WellingtonD "*Indy 10.5.8.0*" - that is an EXTREMELY OLD version of Indy that is no longer supported. The latest version is 10.6.2. You really need to upgrade your copy.

Answer (score 0):

As @zed commented, the problem is my OpenSSL version, it cannot be 1.1.1.
I installed 1.0.2 version from [here](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) and it's working now!

Comment: V1.1.0+ support is coming soon for Indy.  You can read about it [here](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/183).  There's a branch that's in development if you want it, and a (near complete?) fork posted in the link above.